# How to compose query using the @Query annotation and HQL

Tags: jpa, hql

Can somebody help how to compose a HQL query with JPA @Query on the following line?

"get me all books which has this author and are published after year X"

Consider a simple entity without relationship - more concern on the JPA @Query and HQL combination:

```
@Entity

public class Book{
  @Id
  public int id;
  public String title,
  public String authorName;
  public String yearOfPublish;
  .....
```

}

Comment: Can you please show your entity model

Comment: Yet to create...You can Consider a simple one with date of year as String

Comment: Without the entity model I cannot tell you how the query should look like.

Comment: You are mentioning @Query. Do you use Spring DataJPA?

Comment: Yes. Im using Spring Data JPA Repository...Assume I defined a method:

List<Book> getBooksByAuthorAnd GreaterThenYear(String authorName, String year )

Answer (score 1):

The query would be:

```
select b from Book b where b.authorName = :authorName and yearOfPublish > :year
```

And as you are using Spring Data JPA you don't even need to write the Query! Simply write a method:

```
List<Book> findAllByAuthorNameAndYearOfPublishGreaterThan(String authorName, String yearOfPublish);
```

This will create the query for you.

Read for about Query methods in the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods